# Vim block-yanking until a certain character and block-paste in same position

Tags: ruby, vim, vi

I am facing this code:

```rb
@store= Store.new(name:"Storename",
                  address:"Main road, 2",
                  phone:677879878,
                  city:"bluecity",
                  email:"storename@gmail.com.com")

it{ should respond_to(:toreplace)}
it{ should respond_to(:toreplace)}
it{ should respond_to(:toreplace)}
it{ should respond_to(:toreplace)}
it{ should respond_to(:toreplace)}
```

And I would like to turn it into this other one:

```rb
@store= Store.new(name:"Storename",
                  address:"Main road, 2",
                  phone:677879878,
                  city:"bluecity",
                  email:"storename@gmail.com.com")


it{ should respond_to(:name)}
it{ should respond_to(:address)}
it{ should respond_to(:phone)}
it{ should respond_to(:city)}
it{ should respond_to(:email)}
```

I would like to "block-yank" all hashkeys, eg :name, from the contructor call and "block-paste" them in place within the `()`.
I was wondering whether there is a way to "block-yank until a certain character `:` acroos all lines", and then "block paste those", I can only seem to "block-yank" the first character of each line!

*Note*: I would like to avoid macros and REGEX if possible. Though I'm open to macro ideas too that can improve my own.

Answer (score 4):

using blocked selection/yanking and pasting cannot transform the text as you expected, unless you "prepare" the text, specially the `@store` statement. because right now the hash keys are not in a block.

However, your task could be done by macro.

```
qq0f:yb6+;pldt)5-q
```

pressing above keys with your cursor on the `@store` line. after pressing those, your cursor would be on `address`, then press `4@q`, you have got what you wanted.

Note that the `6 and 5` in macro is harded coded. you may want to adjust them depends on your real text. But you got the idea.

it works like:

[image]

Comment: oh, that's advanced to me, I'll have to review it first to understand it properly. thanks, i'll get back to this!

Comment: it wasn't *that* advanced at the end for me :) I just didnt know about the +/- signs. I like your macro much more than mine (which was even more hardcoded). I will wait a day or two to see if there's some other macro-free way before accepting the answer . thanks again.

Comment: Instead of `6+;` I would use `/:toreplace<CR>`, and then instead of `5-` I would use `<C-O>j`.

Comment: @benjifisher if the text `toreplace` is fixed, your suggestion works.

Comment: Not what he asked for, but useful answer. Voted up.

Answer (score 4):

As @Kent said, this cannot be done with block yanking/putting.

I will not try to improve on your macros without knowing what they are.

For the sake of others who might have the same question, without your restrictions, here is an interesting way to do it.  This might be expanded into a reusable function.  First,

```
:let args = []
```

Next, select the lines with the hashkeys and enter Ex mode with <kbd>:</kbd>.  The range `'<,'>` will be entered automatically.  Complete that to

```
:'<,'>g/^/let args += [matchstr(getline('.'), '\k*\ze:')]
```

This should save the hashkeys in the `args` list; you can check with `:echo args`.  Finally, select the lines with the replacement text and enter

```
:'<,'>g/:\zstoreplace/s//\=remove(args, 0)
```

Comment: this is also advanced for me, i'll have to understand it first, thanks, i'll review it.

Comment: This way is truly new to me, i'll research more about turning it into a reusable function, will come in handy. I really appreciate the idea!

Comment: I dont' agree it can't be done with block yanking/putting. See my answer. A bit convoluted to write down, but easy to understand I think.

Comment: Not what he asked for, but very nice way to do it. Voted up.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly off-topic way:

You start by yanking the `@store` paragraph:

```
yip
```

Then you paste it after itself:

```
}p
```

Then you use `:normal` to run a simple macro on every line between the current one and the last one that was pasted:

```
:,']norm 0f:bc0it{ should respond_to(:<C-v><CR>;C)}<CR>
```

Breakdown:

```
:,']                       from current line to last pasted line
norm                       run the following normal mode comman
0                          jump to first column
f:                         jump to first :
b                          jump to beginning of word on the left
c0                         change from cursor to first column
it{ should respond_to(:    type that text
<C-v><Esc>                 literal <Esc>
;                          jump to first :
C                          change from cursor to EOL
)}                         type that text
```

Comment: Not what he asked for, but definitely a best way to do it from the beginning (without previously having the toreplace block). Voted up.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it using mainly block yank/put commands.

The trick is, to be able to do an irregular (not squared) block yank, first make sure what you want to yank is at the end of the line.

So:

1. Select line with attribute names: `ggV5G`
2. On each line, delete everything after attribute name: `:normal f:D`<kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Block-yank attribute names into register "a": `?name`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>`5G$"ay`
4. Restore previous lines, not to lose anything: `u`
5. Block-select "toreplace" lines: `/toreplace`<kbd>Enter</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-V</kbd>`11Gt)`
6. Put attribute names: `"ap`
7. (Optional) Delete extra spaces before closing parentheses: `gv:normal f:f dt)`<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Steps 1-6 give you the following:

```
it{ should respond_to(:name   )}
it{ should respond_to(:address)} 
it{ should respond_to(:phone  )}
it{ should respond_to(:city   )}
it{ should respond_to(:email  )}
```

Step 7 (optional) is to remove extra spaces before closing parentheses, which gives you:

```
it{ should respond_to(:name)}
it{ should respond_to(:address)}
it{ should respond_to(:phone)}
it{ should respond_to(:city)}
it{ should respond_to(:email)}
```

Comment: This is actually the closest to what I wanted to do. I was intending to do exactly this but without having to delete(although in your approach is only temporarily) the content after `:`, i.e. irregular(different length across lines) block-yank/select. I'm getting some nice ideas from your answer, I'll wait to see if there's other nice suggestions.thanks!

Comment: You're welcome. I know you would like something like block selecting the first column of attribute names and then doing `t:` to select until the colon in each line, and then `y` yank just that. Unfortunately, this is currently not supported by vim. As far as I know, the only irregular (not squared) selection you can do is until  the end of line, thereby the need to temporarily delete everything from colon until eol. That's why @Kent said it couldn't be done without *preparing* the text. In any case, I think that's no big deal as deletion is temporary.

Comment: In fact, I find that pattern (transform a text until you get what you want to extract, then copy to register, then undo) very useful in general.

Comment: In any case, to avoid deletion you can try another strategy: 1) Copy attributes block (neccesarily squared without deleting), using width of longest attribute name. 2) Block paste into toreplace block. 3) Delete everything from end of attribute name to closing parentheses on each line (i.e., adapt step 7 of previous strategy). -- I personally prefer previous strategy, as step 3 of this other one can get messier, depending of what comes after attribute names.

Comment: that's a good alternative! I also prefer the former one you suggested tho.